# Is this UPS Socket Defective?

Tags: ups

I have 2 UPS of the exact same model. In one UPS, all of my Type B Plugs would not fit

In the first image, the hole on the socket is on the edge. My Type B Plugs (3 pin) would not fit. On the second image, the hole on the socket is on the middle and my Type B Plugs (3 pin) would fit. For reference, the last image shows what a Type B Plug looks like.

[image: UPS with defective socket]
[image: UPS with working socket]
[image: What a Type B Plug looks like]

Edit: As it might be a "Fake" I included the picture of the serial number of the back of each UPS.

The first image shown is the UPS' serial with the plug that fits. The second image shown is the UPS' serial where the plug does not fit.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What make/model UPS do you have? It appears to be a "world" model that will accommodate multiple different plugs, but may be a "rest-of-the-world" model that will not support US plugs.

Comment: APC BACK-UPS 1400. I have two of these same models yet they have different sockets

Are there actually different socket types? If so what are they called?
@FreeMan

Comment: I have a house full of APCs, yet none of mine have outlets anywhere near what you've got - they're a standard 3-prong 15a US outlet. What is the full model spec from the back of each unit? Maybe even a picture of the label. I'll bet that there is _some_ difference in the fine details, even though they're both "BACK-UPS 1400"s. Maybe pictures of the labels would help someone ID the differences for you. Maybe one is a cheap knockoff that you unwittingly purchased somewhere... :(

Comment: I purchased both from the same computer shop. 
This is the one that fits: https://imgur.com/z7xkzYl
This is the one that does not fit: https://imgur.com/Bu3szz2
@FreeMan

Comment: Very odd. If they're new, I'd take back the one that's not working and ask for an exchange. Unbox it in store and make sure that a standard plug will fit. Very strange...

Comment: Alright will do. I'll be taking to APC as well, I still have the receipt of both units and the "defective" UPS that does not fit the Type B plug is well under 1 year used.

Comment: Do come back and post the results in order to help others out who may run into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

That **is** a valid type of socket. See [the APC manual for the BX-1400 MS](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_File_Name=AHUG-9MQ5LP_R0_EN.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=SPD_AHUG-9MQ5LP_EN&p_enDocType=User+guide).

However, I would be **extremely careful** plugging any US type B plugs into this UPS. As far as I can tell, this is a 230V UPS. The US type B (aka NEMA 5-15) is normally used for 120V devices. If your device comes with a type B plug and, like most **but not all** computers, monitors and laptop power bricks made in the past several years is rated for 100V - 240V (or similar) then this will work fine. However, if you have a device that requires 120V (or 100V - 125V) power, using it with this UPS is a very bad idea.

All that being said, if the socket on one UPS works correctly and on another it does not, take it back to the store.

Comment: My mains on my country is 220V. We do not use NEMA connectors here

Now I know why, that socket MUST BE for NEMA 5-15 and Not US Type B. 
Afaik, NEMA 5-15 and US Type B are two different plugs, they're not the same even if they look very similar. NEMA is prevalently used on the US, while the "US Type B" I'm referring to is the one used in US, Japan and Philippines.

It is very strange that a UPS "Made in Philippines" has a NEMA socket, which is not used in the country. I'm lead to certainly believe its a manufacturing defect.

Comment: The NEMA 5-15 and US Type B **are exactly the same thing** - the standard US electrical system 15A 120V plug/socket. Period. The connector on this UPS is actually designed to connect to a bunch of different things including NEMA 5-15/US Type B. It is **not** an actual NEMA 5-15 socket - a real NEMA 5-15 has exactly-and-only the spaces needed for a Type B plug. As far as "made in Philippines", that has nothing to do with it - there are products made all over the world to specifications for (and export to) places using different electrical, RF, safety and other standards. Made **for** the

Comment: Philippines is a different story altogether.

Comment: Besides, the US *has* a plug/socket for 240V.  It's called NEMA 6.

Answer (score 2):

It's a sourcing problem. The problem is, those "everything sockets" are impossible to make in a safe and reliable form... and as such, UL will never approve one.  Because of that, there's no such thing as an RU-Recognized (UL approved) socket, and people who make UPS's have no other choice but to buy cheap Chinese sockets.   That means the sockets are not reliable.

#### So, this is a quality/warranty issue. Back to the store it goes.

The type of plug that you call "Type B" has a proper name: NEMA 5-15.  It is made for 120V only!  Philippines has 240V center-ground - and while that's unusual, there is a *very similar* NEMA 6-15 type which is designed exactly for 220V center-ground.  If you must use a NEMA plug, use NEMA 6-15.   However it probably won't play nice with the hokey "everything socket".

So stop using NEMA 5-15 for 220V.  Use Europlug, BS1363, Schuko, Australian plugs,  *anything* but NEMA 5!

A BS1363 in particular will be more reliable in those "everything sockets". I believe that is a type "G".